# relative paths and compile problem in windows cmd

Tags: compiling, paths, relative

Tying to write a [BATCH file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) in windows cmd to compile/update all PDF under each folder.

Silly me wasn't really thinking about the larger maintenance issue while started my "little" project.

So I am having some "relative path" issues.
Tying to write a BATCH file in windows cmd to compile/update all PDF under each folder.

Here is what I have

```
<some path>/main_preable.tex
<some path>/1991/report.tex
<some path>/1991/figs/ <- where the graphs are for 1991
<some path>/1992/report.tex
<some path>/1992/figs/ <- where the graphs are for 1992
<some path>/1993/report.tex
<some path>/1993/figs/ <- where the graphs are for 1993
<some path>/1994/report.tex
<some path>/1995/report.tex
<some path>/19XX/figs/ <- where the graphs are for 199XX
```

What I have put in main_preable.tex is

```
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}
```

and for each report.tex we have

```
\input{../main_preable.tex}
```

and it works fine each time when I compile the reports from each of their folders. No problem doing one by one.

Now open cmd from

I tried to use

```
pdflatex "1992\report.tex"
```

Then it couldn't find the paths for the folders...

How and which paths should I modify, so I can update and compile them from cmd in  by something like

```
pdflatex "1992\report.tex"
pdflatex "1993\report.tex"
pdflatex "1994\report.tex"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but `pdflatex "1992/report.tex"` is probably safer to use and supported by Windows.

Comment: @daleif if I use this, it wouldn't even find the main_preable.tex, I'd have to change to "\input{./main_preable.tex}", and I don't want to mess up too much of it as the moment.

Comment: I would probably write a program that goes into each of the years one at a time, and then compile there. And include the preamble as `\input{../main_preable.tex}` as you do. I think that is much much safer and less error prone.

Comment: don't do `pdflatex "1992/report.tex"` do `cd 1992; pdflatex report.tex` (it is _possible_ to do the former but getting the cofiguration correct so that everything finds what it needs to find is so much harder it is never worth the trouble)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmmmm, it wouldn't seem to be able to put in a single line on the bat file....then might have to come up with a better way to loop into and loop out of the folder....but thanks. It's definitely a good different approach!

Comment: Really?  in a unix shell script you can do exactly as I wroee with `;` I assumed windows cmd had something similar but presumably you can have multi-line body of a for-loop, so it isn't an issue. Note that all file references in tex are relative to the tex process not the document. If `report.tex` has `\input{chapter1}` then if you do as I suggest `chapter1.tex` needs to be in the same direcory as `report.tex` but if you do as you suggest it needs to be in the parent directory, (so different reports can not all have a `chapter1.tex` ) *so removing `../` answers the question but do no do it)